# kviy: How to change Labels properties remotly from another class through an iterative sentence

Tags: python, kivy, label

I need to change the text in some Labels ive created with a loop sentence.
Here is what i've done, but it does not seem to work

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.relativelayout import RelativeLayout

class MyUI(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        for i in range(0, 8):
            lbl = Label(text=str(i*10))
            self.add_widget(lbl)

class MainWindow(BoxLayout):

    my_ui = ObjectProperty()
    new_text = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g']

    def change_text(self):
        for letter in self.new_text:
            if self.my_ui.lbl.text == '30':
                self.my_ui.lbl.text = letter

class MainApp(App):
    pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    MainApp().run()
```

And for the kivy file:

```
MainWindow:

<MainWindow>:
    my_ui: my_ui
    MyUI:
        id: my_ui
    Button:
        text: 'Update Labels'
        on_release: root.change_text()

<MyUI>:
```

I also don´t know how to target certain label. And I need to do the initialitation of the label box layout through a for loop.

Comment: That's because you are not addressing the labels at all. One way will be like, iterating over the `my-ui`'s `children`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do something like that by keeping a list of the `Labels` created. This version of `MyUI` does that:

```
class MyUI(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyUI, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.lbls = []  # create list of Labels
        for i in range(0, 8):
            lbl = Label(text=str(i*10))
            self.add_widget(lbl)
            self.lbls.append(lbl)  # add this Label to the list
```

Then in the `change_text()` method you can loop through the list of `Labels`:

```
def change_text(self):
    for letter in self.new_text:
        for lbl in self.my_ui.lbls:  # loop through the list of Labels
            if lbl.text == '30':
                lbl.text = letter
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively, you can iterate over `my_ui`'s `children`.

```py
    def change_text(self):
        for i, child in enumerate(self.my_ui.children[:]): # or, enumerate(self.my_ui.children[::-1]) depends on the order.
            if child.text == '30':
                child.text = self.new_text[i]
```